# ViewFlipper Dinamico - Android

Tags: android, imageview

Olá,preciso criar um viewFlipper dinamico com 12 ImagesView ou seja quando carregar a activity preciso que esse Flipper carregue as imagens para mim. Segue abaixo meu codigo:

No XML

```
    <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/rflipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:autoStart="false"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible">
    </ViewFlipper>
```

na Activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);
      int images[] = R.drawable.imv1, R.drawable.imv2, R.drawable.imv3, R.drawable.imv4, R.drawable.imv5, R.drawable.imv6, R.drawable.imv7, R.drawable.imv8, R.drawable.imv9, R.drawable.imv10, R.drawable.imv11, R.drawable.imv12};
      vFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.rflipper);
      vFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
      vFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
      for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++)
      {
        setFlipperImage(images[i]);
      }
      vFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
      vFlipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
      vFlipper.showNext();
    }
    private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
      Log.i("Set Filpper add", res+"");
      ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
      image.setBackgroundResource(res);
      vFlipper.addView(image);
    }
```

Quando eu testo esse código não apresenta nenhum erro apenas não mostra o Flipper consequentemente não mostra as imagens.
Imagino que seja falta de mostrar algum view ou show do FLipper para mostrar ele, porem não sei como fazer isso.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Experimente eliminar a linha `vFlipper.setAutoStart(true);` e substituir `vFlipper.showNext();` por `vFlipper.startFlipping()`

Comment: ramaral: funcionou era isso mesmo obrigado!